# php won't detect all spaces in a string

Tags: php

I've got a string that comes from a POST form where I want to replace all spaced with some other character.

Here's that I did:

```
$cdata = str_replace(" ","#",$cdata);
```

And I got this.

```
--- Contact-ID#=#148 [10274da8]#Sinhronizācija#=#private [1000137d]#Uzvārds#=#Zom [1000137c]#Vārds#=#Tana [1000130e]#Tālrunis#=#3333 [1000130e]#Mobilais#=#5555
```

As you can see, spaced before "[10..." are still there. Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: would you able to post the correct $cdata value?

Answer (score 4):

It's mostly likely because it's a newline character, `\n`. The first param of `str_replace` can be an array of characters to replace. Could also be a tab char. Or use preg_replace to replace all whitespace chars instead.

**EDIT:**

`$chars_to_replace = array(" ", "\t","\n","\r","\o","\x0B");

$new_string = str_replace($chars_to_replace, "#", $cdata);`

Comment: Hmm... very strange, I replaced all whitespace characters in the manual ( " ", "/t","/n","/r","/o","/x0B" ) and it still doesn't seem to work... any other ideas?

Comment: You're using the wrong slash (forward slash). You need to use a backslash (/).

Comment: I totally had that backwards. Backslash = \

Comment: LOL, thanks. edited the slash, $cdata = str_replace("\t","#",$cdata); ... still the same problem.

Comment: Aha... I tried this  $cdata = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "#", $cdata); and it actually removed that mystical whitespace, as well as lost of other useful characters, but still it shows that its some whitespace character to blame... what else could it be?

Comment: added: after preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "#", $cdata); I see #r#n where the whitespaces where. Yet if I try $cdata = str_replace("\r\n","#",$cdata); it doesn't help.

Comment: Try this:
$chars = array(" ", "\t", "\n"); 
$cdata = str_replace($chars, "#", $cdata);

Answer (score 1):

You need `preg_replace` here:

```
$cdata = preg_replace('/\s+/', '#', cdata);
```

Comment: You don't really need to use regex for such simple thing. There's other problem in this case as Calvin L describes.

Comment: @Ondrej Slinták: That's right, he spotted the problem, no need for regex here.

Comment: yea... tried $cdata = preg_replace('/\s+/', '#', $cdata); , doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @user296516: It is because of the reason figured out by Calvin.

Comment: yes, but str_replace of all whitespace characters ( " ", "\t","\n","\r","\o","\x0B" ) doesn't seem to work either...

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!!! HA-HA-HA!
Being a good programmer I had used mysqli_real_escape_string on $_POST before assigning it to $cdata.
Now I removed it and seems to work perfect! Thanks guys!